# Difference between creating object in the constructor and creating object in declaration

Tags: java, swing, object, constructor

what is the difference of this two codes snippet

### first one

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mainframe extends JFrame {

    private JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel( "Name" );
    private JTextField nameTf = new JTextField( "10" );

}
```

### second

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mainframe extends JFrame {

    private JLabel nameLbl;
    private JTextField nameTf;

    public Mainframe() {
        nameLbl = new JLabel( "Name" );
        nameTf = new JTextField( "10" );
    }

}
```

Comment: It has no different until you decide to use final
e.g. private final JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel( "Name" );

Comment: Read <Thinking in java>, it explain a lot basic thing like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference in your particular case.

But generally, if you wanted to initialize your object with some custom values, then you do it in a constructor.

example :

```
public Mainframe(String name, String number) {
    nameLbl = new JLabel( name );
    nameTf = new JTextField( number );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating object of any variable in constructor and in declaration is **similar**

see the example below:

```
public class DemoClass {

  String str;
  String newStr = new String("I am initialized outside");

  public DemoClass() {

    System.out.println(newStr);
    str = new String("I am initialized inside");
    System.out.println(this.str+"\n");

  }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DemoClass dc = new DemoClass();

  }
}
```

In the above example you can see --
In the constructor the variables are getting initialized, as the object of DemoClass
is already created in the memory by JVM before calling the constructor.

**Constructors** are meant only for initializing any instance variable.

***Flow of creating object:*** Before creating the DemoClass object, JVM will create the depended object i.e. **newStr** will be created first, and then DemoClass object will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality wise there is none. But if you have multiple constructors in second case and if you are creating Object via non default constructor then the instance variables will remain null.

Answer (score 0):

Internally ,the instance variable declaration and your constructor code becomes same in the bytecode.Even the initializer block gets merged in the following order :-

```
1)Instance member declaration
2)All initializer block declarations in the order of their occurence
3)Constructor code
```

After compilation,bytecode treats it as one

Answer (score 0):

The explicit initialization of object fields is copied into every constructor (non-argument constructor or argument constructors) by compiler.